# InstaPy2 fork: example for like by hashtag

Tags: python, instapy

InstaPy (https://github.com/InstaPy/InstaPy) doesn't work anymore and there is a recommendation to use the fork InstaPy2 (https://github.com/InstaPy2/InstaPy2).

Unfortunately, the documentation does not have an example of how to like posts of a particular hashtag. Could you please help me? Here is my attempt that doesn't work:

```
from instapy2 import InstaPy2
session = InstaPy2()
session.login(username='myName', password='myPW')
pk = ["macrophotography"]
session.like(amount=2, iterable=[pk], type=0)
```